# ng-click on button that is ng-included

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem. I'm trying to include a button that's on a html template page on to my index.html page. I do it like this

```
<ng-include src="'logout/logout.template.html'"></ng-include>
```

The page is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="$ctrl.lala()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" ></span> Log out
</button>
```

The problem is, the thing doesn't work. It won't access the ctrl function. As I read, ng-include doesn't work well with other angular directives so my question is, how else can I include my button template in the index.html without copy pasting the code because it's connected to a componenet an dservice so I can't break it.

The componenent:

```
'use strict';
angular
    .module('logout')
    .component('logout', {
        templateUrl: 'logout/logout.template.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$location', '$localStorage', 'Logout',
            function LogoutController($scope, $location, $localStorage, Logout) {


                this.lala = function () {
                    console.log("doing logout");
                }
            }

        ]
    });
```

Comment: It is my understanding that `ng-include` creates a new child scope. So your function `lala()` does not exist in the scope it is being called.

Comment: have you tried this as well ? - `<div ng-include src="'logout/logout.template.html'"></div>`

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa tried, still not working.

Comment: @ksav so then what's the solution? How can I do what I want?

Comment: can you please show code of the controller where method lala() exists?

Comment: added in the post

Comment: assign your `lala()` function to a `$scope` variable - `$scope.lala = function () { console.log("doing logout"); }`. Also make sure its in the right controller.

Comment: how should I call it in ng-click?

Comment: No, just like what i typed previously above.

Comment: Just do -> `ng-click="lala()"`.

Comment: why you just not using this component with <logout></logout> ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa it doesn work

Comment: @AlexanderSuvorov what component is that? where from? any documentation?

Comment: sure: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component
you dont need ng-include here as long as you declaring component 'logout'

Comment: can you create a Fiddle for the same.

Comment: I can't find the logout component anywhere. I don't know what you mean, sorry. I'm new to angular

Comment: you just created it by yourself, read the off docs I shared

Comment: Is the `<button>` code part of your `LogoutController` ?

Comment: Can you try what happens if you add an extra attribute `ng-controller="LogoutController"` on your `<button>` tag.

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: @AlexanderSuvorov I already have that component. if I write <logout></logout> my button appears but it still doesn't do anything

Comment: do you have ng-click="$ctrl.lala()" in the logout`s template?

Comment: @AlexanderSuvorov You can see in my code that yes, I did it. The button code is my entire template

Answer (score 1):

I know it sounds like an overkill, but I would just create another component for it. If lala() is the function that actually logs the user out then it's best to include that in the component too, so you don't have to repeat it in every parent component.

Take a look at this jsfiddle for a complete sample. I wrote everything in the html, but I copied the important part below:
https://jsfiddle.net/6cjd5ggq/1/

```
<logout></logout>

angular.module('logoutapp')
   .controller('logoutController', logoutController)
   .component('logout', {
      // you can use templateUrl, but it's easier this way in jsfiddle
      template: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="$ctrl.lala()">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out
                 </button>`,
      controller: 'logoutController'
});

function logoutController() {
  this.lala = function() {
    alert("logout!");
  };
}
```